# Hiding UITableView separator behind the contentView(cell.imageView)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

in ios 7 i am using cell built in image view, it behind cell image view but i am try a layout subviews in uitableview custom cell like that

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5.0f , 5.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f);
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(60.0f, self.textLabel.frame.origin.y,   self.textLabel.frame.size.width, self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

image view is set correctly but seperator line in imageview side is empty how to seperator line above a imageview or only way to custom imageview

Comment: set imageview as the "scale to fill".

Comment: i tried but seperator line hide depends on original size of image

Comment: give cell height more like around: 100 and also give other seperatorcolor and then check .then you get more idea.

Comment: @Dev patel: when cell height increase propotionally default cell built image view size also increase, so it also hide seperator line.

Comment: disable the default separator and add your own separator, a 1 point height view, with black background and 0.3 alpha.

Comment: @CalinChitu :Thanks for your reply, i know instead of using cell built in imageview use custom image view to add and also custom separator line to add to rectify this error,but i need to know any way to solve in built in function without customize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i add the following line in viewdidload

```
[self.tableviewName setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

now seperater line show fully